# Como recuperar as chaves do firebase? Javascript

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, firebase, firebase-database, id

Boa noite, tenho a seguinte estrutura de dados:
[image: Firebase]

Eu preciso armazenar  todos esses IDs que são filhos de ***visitas*** em um array para posteriormente criar um ciclo de repetição para buscar os dados que cada um desses IDs possui, porém na documentação não consta um método para fazer isso, então achei esse site https://www.it-swarm.dev/pt/javascript/como-recuperar-varias-chaves-no-firebase/825394279/, ali mostra uma pergunta bem semelhante, minha pergunta se realmente não tem outro jeito de fazer isso?

Obs: Meu objetivo é fazer calculos de quantos pneus foram coletados e quantos foram entregues por vendedor, por isso tenho a necessidade de acessar os IDs de cada um,
[image: Nó aberto]

Lembrando que estou usando em javascript para posteriormente criar uma tela para consumir esses dados
segue meu codigo:

```
 firebase.database().ref('visitas/').on('value', function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log(document.createTextNode(item.val()));
            resultado[i] = document.createTextNode(item.val());
            i++;
        })
    });
    console.log(resultado)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As vezes não é nem necessário consultar a documentação, você já tentou fazer um `console.log(item)` só pra saber o que tem dentro? Dentro você deve encontrar a chave `item.payload.doc.id` que é o id do documento em questão.

De qualquer maneira se você está pensando em fazer algo do tipo somente para poder contar a quantidade de documentos que você tem dentro de uma `collection` eu sugiro que você pare por aqui ao menos que você tenha muito dinheiro pra gastar atoa. Firebase é grátis, até um certo ponto. Imagine o seguinte cenário:

- Dentro da `collection` visita você tem 1000 documentos.
- Cada vez que o usuário abre o seu app você lê estes 1000 documentos somente para pegar o id deles e depois processar os dados que você quer.

Suponhamos que em 1 dia um único usuário visite essa página 10 vezes, você já vai ter 10000 leituras só de um usuário em uma única `collection`, não será suficiente para ser cobrado, mas a situação pode ficar grave se o número de pessoas usando seu app aumentar, por isso é necessário entender o funcionamento do Firebase e reduzir ao máximo o número de operações feitas no database por usuário. Uma solução para este problema seria criar uma `cloud function` que controlar cada vez que um documento for escrito / deletado da `collection A` visitas e em base ao tipo de operação realizada você atualiza um único documento em uma  `collection B` com o número de documentos presentes e os valores que você precisa. Desta forma ao invés de ler os 1000 documentos de `A` você vai ler um único documento em `B` e que já contem o número de documentos atualizados. De uma olhada neste [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NegFl9p_sE&feature=emb_title) para entender como Firebase cobra seus usuários.

Comment: Eu usei 'item.key' assim me retornou a chave, sim eu tava desatento sobre a questão de pagamento, obrigado pelo alerta e vou dar uma estudada sobre 'cloud function', eu optei pelo firebase devido a possibilidade de sincronização de dados mesmo com a falta de recursos como internet e bateria, obrigado mesmo!!